# I need to come up with a rule for a set and their relation

Tags: relations, order-theory, equivalence-relations, computational-mathematics, function-and-relation-composition

2 different Set Relations.  I need to come up with a rule for each Relation.

R1 = {(a,b) ∈ A x A : ***rule***} 
where A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12}

I know that they're all positive integer and are divisors of 12.

How could I create a rule for this?
Would it be something like
R1= {(a,b) ∈ A x A :   a|b  }

Relation 2
R2 = {(a, b) ∈ B x B : ***rule***}
where B = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

Would the rule for this relation be
R2 = {(a, b) ∈ B x B : a ≥ 1 and b ≤ 5 }
or maybe 
R2 = {(a, b) ∈ B x B : x ∈ N, 1 ≤ x ≤ 5 }

If it helps to make more sense I was given directed graphs for each relation:

Relation 1 had a directed graph showing the relation as
(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 6), (1, 12), (2, 4), (2, 6), (2, 12), (3, 6), 
(3, 12), (4, 12), (6, 12)

Relation 2 had a directed graph show the relation as
(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)

Any help or a link you think would explain creating rules would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks to me like your first relation is {(x,y)|y> x and x|y} (that last is x evenly divides y).

Comment: Thanks, i was thinking about y > x at the time but that makes sense now

Answer (score 1):

As user247327 says, your first relation looks like $\{(a,b) \in A \times A : a < b \text{ and } a|b\}$. This is the set of pairs $(a,b) \in A \times A$ where $a$ is less than $b$ and $a$ evenly divides $b$.

Your second relation looks like $\{(a,b) \in B \times B : b-a \in \{1,2\}\}$. This is the set of pairs $(a,b) \in B \times B$ where the $a$ and $b$ are not equal and at most $2$ apart (and $a$ is less than $b$)

Comment: Thank You.  Looking at Relation 2 with your rule it makes a lot of sense now.  Is that basically saying “b - a is = to 1 or 2 only”

Comment: @adski Yes, exactly.

Comment: @adski I suggest you accept my answer, so it’s concluded. :)

Comment: Haha.  I do.  It makes great sense.  Thank You

Comment: @adski I meant for you to click the ‘tick’ button on the left, haha! I’m glad I helped you though.